# Storing time in Postgres and handling it on Application (Java) side

Tags: java, postgresql

I have heard that postgres supports storing of datetime and time with both timezone and without timezone. Now an application running in JST timezone has to store time on database side. Now for wherever i have read it is suggested that you shall always keep things stored in UTC which can work in case of datetime because upon receiving datetime on application layer i can manipulate it according to my preferred timezone. But if i only want time stored on database side then for that as well shall i store it as UTC time ? If yes then 1 am in JST will result in 4 pm UTC of previous day. so could someone please suggest me what shall be the preferred way of storing time in database ?

As suggest in one of the answer if i read the time in LocalTime then if i store time as 12:00 JST then upon reading on application side it will be 12:00 JST or 12:00 UTC.

Comment: Postgres' "timestamp with time zone" does **not** store the time zone. It only normalizes everything to UTC and adjust the timestamp to the time zone of the client

Comment: Yes correct. But my question is more centric toward how shall i store time on database side. "time" or "time with time zone"

Comment: `timestamp with time zone` - `time with time zone` is pretty much useless: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz

Comment: Yes that makes sense

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "to be aware of the time slots" ? Edit your Question for detail and clarity.

Comment: Are you asking how to store a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone? If so, edit your Question to say so clearly. And edit the title as well. Your Question can be re-opened after rewriting for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If there is even a remote possibility that times will ever be in more than one time zone, then you need to store them in a common well-known time zone, and UTC is the best choice for that.

If you're absolute certain, beyond any shadow of doubt, that the application will only *ever* be used in a single time zone, and that both application and database servers will run in that time zone, then you *can* store the times in that local time zone.

Since such certainty is rare, it is recommended to use UTC.

If the original time zone must be retained, you need a separate column to store the time zone, so it can be re-applied when loaded from the database.

Comment: So if i am storing time with just time and not time with time zone. Then Upon reading the time on application side. I need to run whether the slot is applicable for today or for tomorrow. Then on java side shall i read the time as LocalTime, LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime to make better manipulation.

Comment: @riteshmalav Since it's just a time, you start with `LocalTime`.

Comment: Ok i if i am storing the time on postgres side as time without time zone and reading it java side as LocalTime then in that case as value stored in database 12:00 upon reading in a server running in singapore will be 12:00 JST or 12:00 UTC or 12:00 SGT

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Apparently you want to store a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Use the Java class `java.time.LocalTime` and the standard SQL type `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

```
LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 )
```

…and…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) )
```

## Details

Be aware that an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

> I have heard that postgres supports storing of datetime and time with both timezone and without timezone.

Actually the SQL standard defines:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`
  Track a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Represents a date, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. Common implementations use UTC.
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`
  Tracks a date and time-of-day but without the context of an offset or zone. So this type *cannot* represent a moment, *is not* a point on the timeline. For example, for a value of "noon on the 23rd of January in 2020", we do not know if this means noon in Tokyo, noon in Paris, or noon in Montréal — all very different moments, hours apart.

> Now an application running in JST timezone

`JST` is not a true time zone. [Proper time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) have a name in `Continent/Region` format. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

If by `JST` you meant the time in Japan, use `Asia/Tokyo`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

> to store time on database side to be aware of the time slots.

I have no idea what that means.

> Now for wherever i have read it is suggested that you shall always keep things stored in UTC

When tracking actual moments, yes, generally best to do so in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that is, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Think of UTC as *The One True Time*, and other offsets & zones as mere variations, as localization issues for presentation of data to users. Do most of your business logic, data storage, data exchange, debugging, and logging in UTC. Keep a second clock on your desk set to UTC, seriously. Programmers and sysadmins should learn to think and work in UTC, leaving behind your parochial time zone while on the job.

> which can work in case of datetime because upon receiving datetime on application layer i am manipulate it according to my preferred timezone.

Yes, as discussed above, work your logic in UTC (generally) and present localized to the zone expected by the user. When crucial, confirm with the user their desired time zone.  And make a habit of always including the zone/offset info when displaying a date or time, to avoid ambiguity and confusion.

> But if i only want time stored on database side then for that as well shall i store it as UTC time. If yes then 1 am in JST will result in 4 pm UTC of previous day. Can someone suggest how shall i store time alone in database side.

Do you mean you want to store just the time-of-day without a date and without a time zone? If so, use:

- `LocalTime` in Java.
- `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in standard SQL.

The SQL standard bizarrely defines a `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` type, but **this makes no sense**. Just think about it. And don’t be surprised; this is not the only anti-feature in the SQL standard. Postgres does offer this type, as following the standard is one of the primary goals of Postgres. Likewise, the *java.time* framework in Java includes a `java.time.OffsetTime` class to be compatible, but you will never use it.

Postgres has excellent date-time handling, and does offer the `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` data types.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localTime ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalTime localTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

You might want to apply that time-of-day to a date and time zone to determine a moment by instantiating a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate, localTime, z ) ;
```

See that same moment through the wall-clock time of UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

And adjust to another time zone if desired. Again, same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMontréal = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

Perhaps you want to see the time-of-day in Québec for that moment.

```
LocalTime localTimeMontréal = zdtMontréal.toLocalTime() ;
```

Here is a table of the various date-time types in Java and in standard SQL.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy & modern) and in standard SQL.]

Comment: Ok i if i am storing the time on postgres side as time without time zone and reading it java side as LocalTime then in that case as value stored in database 12:00 upon reading in a server running in singapore will be 12:00 JST or 12:00 UTC or 12:00 SGT

Comment: @riteshmalav Yes. Now please rewrite your Question and title to explain if that was your goal, or you had some other goal. The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to help you individually get your work done, it is to provide a knowledge base for others. Explain your goal, example input, and expected output.

Comment: I have already modified the questions title and it's content how else shall I modify it more. I understand that it may not be understandable to other at first sight but this a slightly complicated perhaps the community here can help me more on how shall I modify the questions